# pythonify or improve python argument validation

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a function which takes in a single argument. What are some ways i can improve the argument validation?

This is the possible argument that can be passed:

```
[
 {"type": "users", "level": 1, "name": "email@domain.com"},
 {"type": "groups", "level": 2, "id": 10001}
]
```

Here's the function:

```py
def function(properties: List[Dict]):
    for i in properties:
        if i["type"].lower() == 'users':
            if not all(['name', 'level']) in list(i):
                raise ValueError(
                        f"missing `name` or 'level' in type = {i['type']}")  # ValueError or SyntaxError
            if not isinstance(i['name'], str):
                raise TypeError(f" {i['name']} should be string")

        elif i['type'].lower() == 'groups':
            if not all(['id', 'level']) in list(i):
                raise ValueError(f"missing 'id' or 'level' in type = {i['type']}")
            if not isinstance(i['id'], int):
                raise TypeError(f" {i['id']} should be string")
```

Thanks for any assistance in making this robust and optimized.

Comment: Your code is functionally fine. Consider posting it on https://codereview.stackexchange.com, but be sure to read the site rules and expectations there first.

Comment: Also, consider looking into `collections.namedtuple` as a means to get rid of the (unnecessary) dicts

Comment: Finally, don't bother validating. This is Python. Just pass on the KeyError if something is missing. Document properly, and let the user be an adult

Answer (score 1):

You could consider breaking the code down into more functions: for instance:

```
def handle_all(properties: List[Dict]):
    for item in properties:
        yield handle_one(**item)


def handle_one(type=None, level=None, name=None, id=None):
    if type.lower() == 'users':
        # ...
    elif type.lower() == 'groups':
        # ...
```

You could even look at other alternatives, like dynamically selecting a function to call based on `property['type']`, and passing the rest of the arguments to that.

```
def handle_user(name=None, level=None):
    # ...

def handle_group(id=None, level=None):
    # ...

functions = {
    'users': handle_user,
    'groups': handle_group,
}

def handle_all(properties):
    for item in properties:
        handler = functions[item.pop('type'))]
        yield handler(**item)
```

Then you could have annotations on all of those to ensure the correct types are passed.

Comment: thanks for the alternatives. I have about 6 different argument validations to do. i'll consider this to see how i can condense or break it out